# C# Voice Command: Wait for input

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form app that recognizes voice commands and then performs the action accordingly. However, I can't figure out how to speak one command after the other.

Code:

```
if (e.Result.Text == "initiate power saving mode")
{
    Taskbar taskbar = new Taskbar();
    taskbar.Show();
    SoundPlayer deacr = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.deacr);
    deacr.PlaySync();
    if (e.Result.Text== "confirm")
    {
        SoundPlayer deacd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.deacd);
        deacd.PlaySync();
        Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
    }
    else if (e.Result.Text == "cancel")
    {
        SoundPlayer cancelled = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.cancelled);
        cancelled.PlaySync();                    
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, or just doing something wrong?

Comment: Create an event? Then paste your code in event handler? Am I missing something?

Comment: The brackets shown in your series of `if` / `else` statements looks 'strange'.  Do you really mean to test for `e.Result.Text== "confirm"` inside of the first `if` block (which has already tested for `e.Result.Text == "initiate power saving mode"`)

Comment: Yes, sort of like if this, then if that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use System.Speech.This is how i do it on my system. You can do the following:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Alexis
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer Alexis = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine startlistening = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    }
// ...
}
```

then in the main form

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt")))));

        _recognizer.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechDetected);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        startlistening.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        startlistening.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("alexis"))));
        startlistening.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(startlistening_SpeechRecognized);
    }
```

then do your coding. Now in order to call the commands you need to create a txt document. and put in the commands one line at a time (do not leave any open lines).

```
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt")))));
```

will trigger the commands, so that way you can call the commands. Also i would not use `if (e.Result.Text == "initiate power saving mode")` i would use it this way `if (speech == "initiate power saving mode")`
so if you wanted to continue you could do this

```
if (speech == "initiate power saving mode")
{
    Taskbar taskbar = new Taskbar();
    taskbar.Show();
    SoundPlayer deacr = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.deacr);
    deacr.PlaySync();
}
else if (speech== "confirm")
{
    SoundPlayer deacd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.deacd);
    deacd.PlaySync();
    Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
}
else if (speech == "cancel")
{
    SoundPlayer cancelled = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.cancelled);
    cancelled.PlaySync();                    
}
```

be sure to put the command "initiate power saving mode" and "cancel" in the commands txt document (case sensitive).

then if you wanted to keep releases down then you can create a tabbed form and add your own custom commands. Hope this helps. But remember this is an example for you to go by.